# Stand Up Paddle Surfing Wetsuit

Tags: equipment, surfing

I'm looking to start Stand Up Paddle Surfing on the Great Lakes in the US and would like to be comfortable and extend the season a little by getting a wetsuit. Are there certain types of suits that would be more suitable? I feel like it will be very difficult to paddle in a typical scuba suit.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, Patagonia's are quite flexible. I live in Chicago and have a number of friends who are fond of their product for winter surfing when the waves really pick up. They would be flexible enough to paddle in. It is all down to person preference so I would recommend trying to go to a store to try one and see. SUP does require a large range of motion so it would be important o find one that is not as rigid as a scuba suit.